# Как считать сообщения пользователя ВКонтакте?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Использую python(3.7) + vk_api и хотел бы считывать сообщения пользователя.
Но так понял было некоторое нововедение недавно, которое сильно все порезало.

1. Можно ли все таки без standalone приложения читать сообщения?
2. Сообственно как считать сообщения через standalone приложение - т.к. мне всегда пишет что то ли у меня, то ли у приложения недостаточно прав для чтения сообщений.

Comment: Никак, всё порезано

Comment: Достаточно получить токен через клиент "Android", дальше читать не проблема.

Comment: @djimbosfan. 
Я делаю на пк.

Comment: А через этот модуль не работает https://github.com/python273/vk_api?

Comment: @gil9red, там все работает, но проблема именно в токене. 
Как снизу указали нужно получить токен, но :
1. Это чужое приложение, которому ты разрешаешь работать с твоими сообщениями(и возможно другими данными - при переходе по ссылке показывается к чему предоставляешь доступ ).
2. И вот проблема в этой самой ссылке - я не сильно разобрался, но все же вроде сделать потверждение, можно только в веб страничке(вроде как убрали форму без браузера). Вообщем тоже неприятный момент, хотя наверное и можно это все решить.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно получать токен из проверенного приложения. Возьмём официальное приложение "Android".

> https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=**ЛОГИН**&password=**ПАРОЛЬ**

После просто выполняем API запрос с получением истории чата.

> https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getHistory?&user_id=**АйдиПользователя**&count=**Кол-воСообщений**&v=5.95&access_token=**Токен**

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить токен от приложения, которому доступна секция `messages`.
Например, Kate Mobile [ссылка для получения токена](https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=2685278&scope=messages&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token&revoke=1).

Если не нужны какие-то разрешения, то можно поменять scope.
Далее, этот токен нужно скопировать и вставить:

```
import vk_api

token = ''
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
api = vk_session.get_api()
print(api.messages.getConversations())
```